# Navigation problems after script adding new row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my spreadsheet I have a trivial script, which is adding a new row and getting the cursor into the second cell of the new row:

```
function rowadd() {
  var d_akt = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var a_akt = d_akt.getActiveSheet();
  var w_akt = a_akt.getActiveRange().getRow();
  a_akt.insertRowsBefore(w_akt, 1);
  a_akt.setActiveRange(a_akt.getRange(w_akt, 2));
}
```

The script runs when a user presses a button in the sheet. Works almost fine, but after the script ends the cursor is in the right cell, but i cant write in that cell without a mouse click. Looks like the navigation is not in the sheet.
Can't find any solution how to fix that issue.

Comment: It works for me. I can add text without clicking the mouse.

Comment: I tried on Chrome and Firefox and nothing. 
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11jOvu1BrbX3xEFrTX3RSL8VnG21wZsgz0cFGL67yZfI) 

When i click the button i get a new row, but I have to click in it to write something.

Comment: I suppose one difference is that I created a menu item because I don ‘t use buttons in sheets. That may change the focus.

Comment: @Cooper - thanks for your response. What do you mean by "menu item". Im not sure if I understand that correctly.
Found a similar problem here:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897408/google-sheets-script-range-activate-still-requires-user-to-click-in-order-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a menu of your own like this:

```
function onOpen()
{
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu').addItem('Description','functionName').addToUi();
}
```

We typically put it in a simple trigger onOpen() function so that it runs whenever you open the file. You can learn more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

Another option is to create a sidebar dialog and put buttons there.  That's a little more effort but the pay of is that you don't have to open up a drop down menu.  You can just click on a button immediately.

Comment: Works OK. Thank you Cooper. 
Strange, that it can't be done on a button made from immage.