# Can't edit field without clicking after a script run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, button

I have a Google Sheets workbook which has some macros defined as scripts. They're very simple (adding rows and formatting). The last line of the script activates a specific cell.

I've linked one of the scripts to a button. When I click the button, the macro runs as expected, and the cell is highlighted as expected, but I'm unable to edit the cell without double clicking on the cell. Even hitting the 'enter' key doesn't allow text to be entered in the cell.

I've looked through the developer reference, and tried searching the internet, but no combination of search terms seem to describe this issue exactly.

Here's the function that I'm using, I want to edit cell B3 when the macro is done:

```
function Insert() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IF(or(ISNUMBER(D3),ISNUMBER(E3)),sum(F4+D3-E3),"")');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBorder(null, null, null, true, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBorder(null, true, null, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3:F4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3').activate();
};
```

I would like to be able to start typing in the cell as soon as the macro is finished running (or if necessary, hit the 'enter' key, then start typing)

Answer (score 3):

After clicking the button you can't write directly into the cell because the button got selected after you clicked it, while ignoring the result of the function itself.

I came to a workaround to this feature while studying [custom menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus). It is possible to use your function to create a new menu; and that menu, after being activated, will leave the cursor in the cell being ready to write as you originally requested.

To get that menu you need to add the following function in your code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var userInterface = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  userInterface.createMenu("cawwot's menu").addItem('Insert', 'Insert').addToUi();
}
```

After reloading the spreadsheet, you will be a able to user your new menu.

---

Your approach is one of the correct ways to move the cursor to a specified cell. To write on that cell you can make double click as you said, but there are faster ways:

- Paste text: just press `CTRL + V`.
- Formula bar: click once on it and write the data.

For clarification, the formula bar is marked with the ƒ symbol on the upper side of the screen. If it is hidden you can make it appear on `View > Formula bar`. We hope that this is useful for you. Please, don't hesitate to offer us more information for further help.

Comment: @cawwot My original answer just got updated. This new version completely fulfills your original request.

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2022, when using Google Apps Script to extend Google Sheets, it's not possible to change the focus from a button to a cell or the formula bar in order to be able to immediately start typing the cell content.

You might press the ESC key to change the focus from the button to active cell, but if this isn't good enough, besides using a custom menu as was suggested in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57866319/1595451), as you are using macros, you might run the script from the Extensions > Macros built-in menu.